# Personalized listview android studio

Tags: android, listview, parsing, android-studio, adapter

(First of all sorry my bad english)

I am doing an app about routes in my town, is like a project of my grade, and I have it done it all but I don't know what is the problem..

My problem is that the ListView that I made from a ViewHolder it doesn't show up when I start the app.

My code is this:

MainActivity:

```
public class RutasActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOGO = "";
    ImageButton btnImgAtras;
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rutas);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvRutas);

        RutasParser parser = new RutasParser(this);

        if(parser.parse()) {

            Ruta[] rutas = parser.getRutas();

            RutaAdapter adapter = new RutaAdapter(this, rutas);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Enseñando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudieron obtener los datos de los países", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        btnImgAtras = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAtras);
        btnImgAtras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(RutasActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RutasActivity"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/escudoazulsinfondo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/Rutas_Javea"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Blacky"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/atras"
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnAtras"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="312dp"
        android:layout_height="358dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvRutas"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/depturismenofondo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then, my AdapterView:

```
public class RutaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ruta> {

    Ruta[] rutas;

    public RutaAdapter(Context context, Ruta[]rutas) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem_ruta, rutas);
        this.rutas = rutas;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View item = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(item == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_ruta, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.vhKm = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.listKm);
            viewHolder.vhNombreRuta = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.listNombre);
            viewHolder.vhDesnivel = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.listDesnivel);
            viewHolder.vhDificultad = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.listDificultad);
            viewHolder.vhTiempoTotal = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.listTiempo);

            item.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)item.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.vhKm.setText(String.valueOf(rutas[position].getDistancia()));
        viewHolder.vhNombreRuta.setText(rutas[position].getNombre());
        viewHolder.vhDificultad.setText(rutas[position].getNivel_dificultad());
        viewHolder.vhTiempoTotal.setText(rutas[position].getTiempo_efectivo());
        viewHolder.vhDesnivel.setText(String.valueOf(rutas[position].getDesnivel_acumulado_ascenso()));

        return item;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView vhNombreRuta;
        TextView vhKm;
        TextView vhDificultad;
        TextView vhTiempoTotal;
        TextView vhDesnivel;
    }
}
```

My parser:

```
public class RutasParser {

    private Ruta[] rutas;
    private InputStream rutasFile;

    public RutasParser(Context c) {
        this.rutasFile = c.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.rutas);
    }

    public boolean parse() {
        boolean parsed = false;
        rutas = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(rutasFile);
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("country");
            rutas = new Ruta[items.getLength()];
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Node item = items.item(i);

                int rutaId = Integer.parseInt(item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("code").getNodeValue());
                String rutaNombre = item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                String rutaDescrip = item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("description").getNodeValue();
                double rutaDistance = Double.valueOf(item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("distance").getNodeValue());
                String rutaHora = item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("horas").getNodeValue();
                String rutaDif = item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("dificultad").getNodeValue();
                int rutaElev = Integer.valueOf(item.getAttributes().getNamedItem("elevacion").getNodeValue());

                rutas[i] = new Ruta(rutaId, rutaNombre, rutaDescrip, rutaDistance, rutaDif, rutaHora, rutaElev);
            }

            parsed = true;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            Log.e("CountryParser", "ParserConfigurationException: "+pce.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("CountryParser", "Unknown Exception: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return parsed;
    }

    public Ruta[] getRutas() {
        return this.rutas;
    }
}
```

And the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00.00km"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/listKm"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingStart="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="nombre de ruta"
            android:id="@+id/listNombre"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listDificultad"
                android:text="dificultad"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listTiempo"
                android:text="000000"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listDesnivel"
                android:text="000000"/>


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

At first place I don´t see any error but it doesn´t show up in my app..

If you can help me, I would be grateful..

Thanks

[Photo of what I tell you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EClQl.png)

Comment: You should debug it yourself, attach the debugger, put a breakpoint at getView method of adapter and check have it ever been called.  Also that parts of your question aren't code snippets, so use code {} bracers instead

Comment: Thank you I will try, i'm noob in stackoverflow I don't know how to use the code things in here and that..

Comment: @Beloo I just debugged it and the method getView is never called.. i don't know why...

Comment: The next step is checking whether or not `Ruta[] rutas` array passed to adapter is empty

Comment: Okey, i just saw the fail and it was on the nodelist when I parse... it took me one week to see this fail... JESUS. In " NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("country");" it was a String fail i should name it "ruta"... Sorry for waste your time @Beloo and thank you for the tips..

Comment: No problem. But you should debug such cases by yourself next time and create more scoped questions to make it useful for whole community